# Migrating ZF2 to ZF3: How to adapt navigation view?

Tags: navigation, migration, zend-view, zend-navigation, zend-framework3

In my ZF2 application I have a this navigation view script:

```
$routeMatch = $this->getHelperPluginManager()
    ->getServiceLocator()
    ->get('Application')
    ->getMvcEvent()
    ->getRouteMatch();
$currentRoute = $routeMatch instanceof \Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch ? $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName() : null;
?>
<?php foreach ($this->container as $page) : ?>
<li <?php echo $currentRoute == $page->getRoute() ? ' class="active"' : null;?>>
    <?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->htmlify($page, true, false) . PHP_EOL; ?>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Since the `getServiceLocator()` is now deprecated, I need another way to get the information about the current route into the navigation view script.

This view script gets set as partial and called in the `layout.phtml`:

```
echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu()->setPartial('navigation/default');
```

So I got the idea to pass the need information via a template variable. I created one in the `Module#onDispatch(...)`:

```
public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
{
    $viewModel = $mvcEvent->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();
    $routeMatch = $mvcEvent->getRouteMatch();
    $viewModel->currentRoute = $routeMatch instanceof RouteMatch
        ? $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName() : null
    ;
}
```

Now I can access it in the `layout.phtml`. But I don't find a way to pass it into the navigation view script, since the [`Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu#setPartial(...)`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/master/src/Helper/Navigation/Menu.php#L645)` doesn's accept any arguments for variables.

**How to pass variables (especially the information about the current route) into the navigation view in Zend Framework 3?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it using `DefaultNavigationFactory`.

Lets say we have some routes as the following

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'world' => [
            'type'    => Literal::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/world',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => [
                'country' => [
                    'type' => Literal::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => '/country',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'controller' => Controller\WorldController::class,
                            'action' => 'country',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Now we would define our navigation configuration under top-level key `navigation` and enable zend navigation. You may put this code into your `config/autoload/global.php`

Depending on the above route configuration our navigation configuration would be like the following

```
// configure the navigation
'navigation' => [
    'default' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Home',
            'route' => 'home',
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'World',
            'route' => 'world', // this should be the route name not route pattern like '/world'
            'pages' => [
                [
                    'label' => 'Country',
                    'route' => 'world/country',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],

// Register the navigation
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'navigation' => Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

Now we would be able to call the navigation view helper using the top key `navigation` from the above configuration into the view script. See below

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <?php 
        echo $this->navigation('navigation')
            ->menu()
            ->setUlClass('nav navbar-nav')
            ->renderMenu(); 
        ?>
</div>
```

That's it!

The following shows how you can restrict routes to the user and set ACL object or user Role object through the navigation helper's setter methods. Here `$this->loggedInUser`, `$this->acl` and `$this->userRole` has been injected to the view script thus

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-menu">

    <?php if ($this->loggedInUser !== null) : ?>
        <?php $this->navigation('navigation')
                ->findBy('route', 'hello')
                ->setParams(array('username' => $this->loggedInUser->getUsername())); ?> // If you need to pass any params

        <?php $this->navigation('navigation')
                ->findBy('route', 'world'); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php 
        echo $this->navigation('navigation')
            ->menu()
            ->setUlClass('nav navbar-nav')
            ->setAcl($this->acl) // ACL object
            ->setRole($this->userRole) // Role Object
            ->renderMenu(); 
    ?>

</div>
```

Hope this would help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's already working. The problem is the setting of the `active` "property" and in general passing variables into the navigation view script.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! It solved the problem.